# Backup file new files only with Powershell

Tags: powershell, backup

I am writing a Powershell script to add only new files to a backup. I have a back up folder and then I add a new file after a minute and it copies all the contents where I only want the new file copied.
So as you can see I am get the files and backing them up in the $Destination folder with the timestamp. After a couple of minutes I add a new file and run the script again and it copies the new added file along with all the other files. I only want the new added file to be copied to the new backup.
What do I need to do to incorporate this??

This is my code:

```
function BackupArtifacts {

Param(
$FileLocation = "C:\TempCopy",
$Destination = "C:\TempCopyBackUp_" + $TimeStamp,
$StartRange = -100,
$NumberOfDays = 5
)

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Destination
$count = 0

foreach ($fileList in Get-ChildItem $FileLocation -recurse) 
{    
    if ($fileList.LastWriteTime -ge ($(Get-Date)).AddDays($StartRange))
    { 
        #Check if file already exists 

        try {
                Copy-Item $fileList.FullName -Destination $Destination -Recurse
                Write-Host $fileList.FullName
                $count ++                                
        } catch {
        Write-Error $_
        }
     }                            
}
Write-Host "Backup complete, Number of files backed up:" $count
}

BackupArtifacts $FileLocation $Destination $StartRange $NumberOfDays
```

Comment: `-lt` --> `-ge`. Also, I would use `Test-Path` to check if the destination already exists and only if not, create it

Comment: Hi, that worked fine. I replaced -lt with -ge. Thanks alot

Comment: Another thing I would like to add as an output of how many file have been backed up. How would I do this?? @Theo

Comment: Easy. Simply initialize a counter variable to 0 above the foreach loop `$count = 0` and increment it inside the `if` with `$count++`. Add that to the output.

Comment: Why not use RoboCopy? Admitting legacy stuff is faster or easier to maintain then PowerShell is not a shame. ;-)

Comment: I have edited my code above. I have added 2 new parameters. $StartRange will go back 100 days and copy any files within the 100 days and the $NumberOfDays will be how many days worth of files to copy. Where will i fit in the $NumberOfDays parameter into the code. Will it be in the if statement or the Copy-Item statement. @Theo,